# PHP file_get_contents get all contents from multiple div by class name

Tags: php, html

I want to grab what's new text from play store whatsapp. I am trying below code, and it's working well.

```
<?php
$url = 'https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.whatsapp&hl=en';
$content = file_get_contents($url);
$first_step = explode( '<div class="recent-change">' , $content );
$second_step = explode("</div>" , $first_step[1] );
echo $second_step[0];
?>
```

The issue is that, this code only show text from first recent-change div class. It has multiple divs with recent-change class name. How to get all content from it?

Comment: [dom de dom dom DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
 and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 and also [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: you have use domdocument a navigation with xpath!

Answer (score 1):

As already suggested in comments you have to use dom content. But if you want to display all text containing `recent-change` class. You can use loop. I am providing solution on same way which you are using

```
$url = 'https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.whatsapp&hl=en';
$content = file_get_contents($url);
$first_step = explode( '<div class="recent-change">' , $content );
foreach ($first_step as $key => $value) {
  if($key > 0)
  {
    $second_step = explode("</div>" , $value );
    echo $second_step[0];    
    echo "<br>";
  }
}
```